# Select users who doesn't have any subscription active (Active Record Query)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have association as following

A user has many subscriptions (only one subscription can have its status as active)
A subscription belongs to a user

I'm looking for an active record query that would help me select users whose all subscriptions are cancelled or in other words who doesn't have any active subscription.

Raw Sql queries are also welcome for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it in two ways

1st one:

```
User.where.not(id: Subscription.where(status: 'active').pluck(:user_id))
```

2nd one:

```
active_subscription_user_ids = Subscription.where(status: 'active').pluck(:user_id)

User.left_outer_joins(:subscriptions).where.not(id: active_subscription_user_ids)
```

Comment: Its possible to make everything in one query, first getting the active subscriptions and them check which users don't have those ids is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
User.joins(:subscriptions).where('subscriptions.status = "active"').group('subscriptions.id').having("count(subscriptions.id) < 1")
```

Comment: So if a user has two canceled subscriptions and one active subscription, it still returns that use because of two canceled subscriptions.

Comment: I've got the answer

In User.rb

scope :inactive_subscriptions, -> { joins(:subscriptions).where.not(id: Subscription.active_user_ids).uniq }

and in Subscription.rb
scope :active_user_ids, -> { where(status: 'Active').pluck(:user_id) }

Comment: I hvae updated the ans could you please try it?

Comment: I tried it, but getting this error
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)

Comment: Yea,, add users.id in group

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this query

```rb
User.where.not(id: Subscription.select(:user_id).where(status: 'Active'))
```